# Kd value no longer exported

Tags: export

I was using the Legacy wavefront object exporter in Blender 3.6.2 together with a python script to batch export some objects for use in another program. Now I'm upgrading the script for use in Blender 4.0 which means I have to use the normal .obj exporter. However the MTL format is different and no longer writes the Kd values. I need these for import in another program. Is there a way to make the 4.0 .obj exporter write the Kd values to the MTL?

Comment: Kd works for me. It should be the color in the Base Color socket on the Principled node when the socket is not connected. Post your node setup.